# What is the simplest Java ORM supporting Sqlite?

Tags: java, sqlite, orm

What is the ORM that can bound to a Java application in the least possible time, given its performance is not important?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is self-marketing but my [ORMLite package](http://ormlite.com/) has native support for Sqlite – as well as MySQL, Postgres, Microsoft SQL Server, H2, Derby, and HSQLDB.  It uses annotations to configure the persisted classes and is simple to get up to speed.

Here is the online docs on how to [get started with the package](http://ormlite.com/docs/getting-started):

I have experience with the `org.xerial.sqlite-jdbc` JDBC driver which seems to work very well.

Comment: The project page says: `It is currently in Early Beta stage and needs testing/input, therefore it is not recommended for production use.` Is it correct?

Comment: Oh I see.  There is another ORMLite at Google code.  Mine is hosted at Sourceforge at the URL http://ormlite.sourceforge.net/ and is production/stable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I got it now. Going to stick with ORMLite and in case any problems appear, I'm going let you know :)

Comment: I'm getting this error in Eclipse `The type org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcDaoSupport cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files` when trying to extend `BaseJdbcDao`. How can I fix it?

Comment: I've fixed the last exception by adding Spring dependency (not very lightweight IMHO though). Seems to be working fine so far, thanks for making it)

Comment: Doesn't support any one-to-many or many-to-many relationships like java.util.list

Comment: ORMLite supports one to many with the foreign collections @Highmastdon.  Many to many you have to do yourself.

Comment: @Gray why do I get the following error then? `ORMLite does not know how to store interface java.util.List`

Comment: Can ormlite only be used on android? i would like to use it in a normal java application, but OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper needs an android context

Answer (score 2):

SQLite is fully supported by [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org).

Answer (score 2):

[Sormula](http://www.sormula.org/) works with any relational database since it creates standard SQL. Sqlite test configuration and jdbc driver are included in the test suites.

Comment: looking good, hopefully the latest version gets pushed to maven central :)

Comment: @ATutorMe, thanks for the support. I observed the clones on GitHub have increased and the downloads on Nexus are showing increase. I will push version 4.4 soon.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [demo project](http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-sqlite/) for Hibernate SQLite integration. [EclipseLInk JPA](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/jpa.php) should also work. EclipseLink is lighter than Hibernate, but Hibernate is better documented and more mature.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveJDBC supports a number of databases, including SQLite3: http://javalite.io/activejdbc#supported-databases